# GEE - How to get the geometry of a feature?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

```js
print(table);
var ElementList = table.toList(3);
print(ElementList);
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  var element = ElementList.get(i);
  print(element);
  var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
                .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT","less_than",20)
                .filterDate('2020-1-1','2021-1-1').filterBounds(element.geometry())
                .map(maskS2clouds).map(add_MNDWI).map(add_NDVI).map(add_EVI).map(add_USI).map(add_UWI);
print(dataset);
```

How to get the geometry of a feature? I searched the functions of `Feature` and found `.geometry()` as I wrote in the code, but I was told that this function is DEPRECATED and need to use `Element.geometry()` which I didn't know how to use it in my code.

`table` is a `FeatureCollection` and I turned it to a `List`, then get every Feature of it which is called `element`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a working example so that we can replicate the error? Also using for loops like this is not recommended, so consider using .map() (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_js_03).

Finally most likely because you loop client side you have to cast your element as a feature like this

```
print(table);
var ElementList = table.toList(3);

print(ElementList);
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  var element = ee.Feature(ElementList.get(i));
  print(element);
  var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
                .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT","less_than",20)
                .filterDate('2020-1-1','2021-1-1').filterBounds(element.geometry())
                .map(maskS2clouds).map(add_MNDWI).map(add_NDVI).map(add_EVI).map(add_USI).map(add_UWI);
print(dataset)};
```

But hard to tell exactly without a working example!

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed my code as you teached me and it worked now. I will update this question for you to repeat my error. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked, if you then could accept the answer for future reference